# C# RegEx Selective Replacement

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I am trying to do a selective replacement, so replace everything in a string but not the characters between [ & ].
For example if the input string is “yyyy[m]mm”, I want to replace all m to upper case (except the ones between [ & ]), the result should be yyyy[m]MM.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give example expected input and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it, at least in your example. It uses a [negative lookbehind and a negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to only match `m`s that are not surrounded by brackets. It will work with `[mm]` but not `[mmm]` or `[mmdd]`.

```
Regex.Replace("yyyy[m]mm", @"(?<!\[)m(?!\])", "M")
```

Comment: Thanks Tim S. that worked. Here is the routine I ended up writing: ''' public string ReplaceSelective(string data, string sourceString, string destString) ''''{ string pattern = @"(?<!\[)" + sourceString + @"(?!\])"; Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern); return (rgx.Replace(data, destString)); }'''

Comment: Use backticks to format code inline. http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax

Comment: You'll probably want to escape your `sourceString`, like so: `Regex.Escape(sourceString)`. That way if the source string is `test.`, it'll still work correctly and not match `"testy"`.